# Angular JS Cross Domain Issue

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

I am using AngularJS $resource to get some data using JSONP.

```
 app.controller('Hello', ['$scope', 'Phone', function($scope, Phone,$http) {

  $scope.data=Phone.query();

}]);
mycallback = function(data,$scope){
  alert(data.found);
};

app.factory('Phone', ['$resource',function($resource){
return $resource('http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/wtmpeachtest.wordpress.com/posts?callback=mycallback', {}, {
  query: 
    {
        method:'JSONP', 
        params:{}, 
        isArray:false,
        callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'

    }
});
}]);
```

The error console shows "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :". Please let me know, how best I can handle JSONP data.

Comment: ok, now i added callback function appended to the url. But inside callback function $scope is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include $scope in factory before accessing it.

```
app.factory('Phone', ['$resource','$scope',function($resource,$scope){}
]);
```

Comment: I implemented that but resulting in the following error.Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider

Comment: such errors come if you are accessing the dependency that was not included or you misspelled.  https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I am able to access the $scope once I put the callback function inside the controller

```
    app.controller('Hello', ['$scope', 'Phone', function($scope, Phone,$http) {

    Phone.query();
    mycallback = function(data){
    $scope.data= data.found;

    };


 }]);
```